For positive real numbers $x,y,z$ with $xy+yz+zx=1$, prove that $\frac{2}{xyz}+9xyz \geq 7(x+y+z).$
As the question suggests, $x, y, z >0$. My first thought was to use A.M-G.M inequality. But this form is not very nice for a direct application of A.M-G.M.
One idea to make the form a little bit better is by replacing $a =xy, b = yz, c =zx$. This means $a+b+c = 1$ and the ultimate to prove part becomes $$9 + \frac{2}{abc} \ge 7\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}\right)$$
Any ideas or just a little hint regarding this method (or any other method) will be appreciated.
Edit: There was a typo. Corrected it.

Shouldn’t it be $2/abc +9$ in the end?

@Pranay yes, it was a typo. Corrected it.

From How to ask a good question: " Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Multiplying by $abc$ throughout, then homogenizing, the given inequality is equivalent to $f(a, b, c) \ge 0$, where $f(a, b, c) := 9abc+2(a+b+c)^3-7(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)$. But, expanding and simplifying, $f(a, b, c) = 2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) - (a^2 b + a b^2 + b^2 c + b c^2 + c^2 a + ac^2)$.
The Arithmetic mean- Geometric mean Inequality gives $2a^3 + b^3 \ge 3 a^2b$. Similarly, $a^3 + 2b^3 \ge 3a b^2$. Therefore $a^3 + b^3 \ge a^2b + ab^2$. Therefore, by symmetry, $f(a, b, c) \ge 0$.

You can search for extrema of $$f(a,b)= 9 + \frac{2}{ab(1-a-b)}-7\left(\frac 1a + \frac 1b +\frac{1}{1-a-b} \right)$$ in the triangle $T = \{(a,b): 0 < a < 1, 0 < b < 1-a\}$. The function is continuous and differentiable in $T$ and becomes arbitrarily large (positive) when we approach the boundary of $T$. Hence, it will have a global minimum, attained at a stationary point. Since the only stationaty point is $(a,b)=(\frac 13,\frac 13)$ and $f(\frac 13,\frac 13)=0$, the result follows.

I have used this approach. But this problem was given to me by a pre-calculus level student. Thus any solution using algebra will be helpful.
